# How can I perform a mathematical function in Column A, where Column B equals a specific value?

Tags: sharepoint

For example, if I have two lists, Alpha and Bravo, where List Alpha is the operational list, and List Bravo draws from List Alpha to display information for administrators:

**List Alpha** (source list)

Column A (Player Name)/Column B (Number of Home Runs)
John/2
John/5
John/11
Mary/3
Suzy/7
Suzy/6

**List Bravo** (administrator list)
Column A (Name)/Column B (Number of Items in Other List)/Column C (Total HRs)
John/3/18
Mary/1/3
Suzy/2/13

Or:

1. List Bravo Column A shows a single instance of each name appearing in List Alpha Column A.
2. List Bravo Column B counts number of items in List A where: List Bravo Column A = List A Column A
3. List Bravo Column C adds up all List Alpha Column B where: List Bravo Column A = List A Column A

I apologize if I'm being unclear, as this is my first attempt at writing a question. Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this with custom code or sharepoint oob functionality? If the second list is not neccessary you probably could create a custom view for the administrators with double grouping to get the same result.

Comment: Thank you. The second list is not necessarily needed. How would I set up the double grouping to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

"Thank you. The second list is not necessarily needed. How would I set up the double grouping to achieve the result?" -Darryl Cooper

This explanation is for sharepoint 2013. The menu may vary for other versions.

Navigate to the list -> In the ribbon select "List" -> "Create View" -> "Standard View" -> Enter a view name -> "Create a Personal View" -> "Select the columns that should be shown (Name/Homeruns) -> Expand the "Group by" section -> First column to group by is "Name" second is "Homeruns" -> Expand the "Totals" section -> "Homeruns" "Sum" -> Finish creating the view

As you might realize this will only generate the view for yourself. It is not possible to customize access to a view with oob functionality.

Here are some options to overcome that:

Free:

Every Administrator creates the view for himself. Note that a user might as well do the same without you knowing it.

Create the view for everyone. If the user has access to the list he could get that information anyway. -> In the view creation menu select "Public View"

$$:

[Custom View Permissions](http://www.boostsolutions.com/de/columnpermission.html)